# Column Vector Sweave \Sexpr

Tags: pdftex, matrices, r, sweave, vector

I'm having big problems trying to compile a file using Sweave displaying a vector defined in an R chunk, as a column vector in Latex using pmatrix, I have something like  this:

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
B=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
@

We have the vector $B$ defined as
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
\Sexpr{print(paste(b,collapse='\\'),quote=FALSE}
\end{pmatrix}$$
```

If I change the text collapse argument to anything don't having a backslash I got no problems, but I need to use the backslash so I can have every number in a different row. Running Sweave returns this error:

```
\Sexpr{print(paste(b,collapse='\\'),quote=FALSE}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sweave has had [this bug](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Sweave-printing-an-underscore-in-the-output-from-an-R-command-td4675177.html) for quite a few years. Hopefully it will get fixed in the next version of R. The [**knitr** package](http://yihui.name/knitr) has been working well with backslashes in `\Sexpr{}`. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
<<echo=FALSE>>=
b = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
@

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
\Sexpr{paste(b, collapse='\\\\\n')}
\end{pmatrix}$$
\end{document}
```

[image: pmatrix from knitr]

Note you need four backslashes in R in order to produce two in LaTeX, and you do not need `print()` here.

See [more on Sweave and knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/).